# Button not enable right click and copy paste some text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm added text type and button enable disable function , but when I right click and copy paste button not enable , any solution for this?

Thanks

```js
function manage(txt) {
  var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
  if (txt.value != '') {
    bt.disabled = false;
  } else {
    bt.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="manage(this)" />
<input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
```

Comment: check onmouseup event.

Answer (score 4):

You could  do with [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event.

```js
function manage(txt) {
  var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
  if (txt.value != '') {
    bt.disabled = false;
  } else {
    bt.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" oninput="manage(this)" />
<input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, its worked for me

Comment: @core114 glad to help you. Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to use **onpaste** event.

```js
document.getElementById("txt").onpaste = manage;

function manage(txt) {
        var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
        if (txt.value != '') {
            bt.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            bt.disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="manage(this)" />
    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
```

More info about that event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste

Comment: Do paste to the input and click to another side of page, it works.

Comment: im not a used down vote, anyway  I wanna just right click copy paste , but don't want to another side click

Comment: ok, im searching another event for that specific use!